# Making equals and contains in groovy behave indentical for numbers

Tags: groovy

We have a "user script" where the goal is to check if a value is in a list.
The input values can be either int or double:

```
int i = 5
double d = 5
println i==d // gives true
```

But

```
println d in [5] // gives false
```

I understand why, int.equals(double ..) is false.
But is there a solution where the user can put ints or doubles in the list without considering the type?

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a solution where the user can put ints or doubles in the
> list without considering the type?

There are, and what is the right thing to do would depend on understanding more about the data, but one option is instead of `d in [5]` you could do something like `[5].any{ it == d }`.